# How to return amortization schedule from yield using dataframe values as input?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with different loan attributes, I need to create a payment schedule for each loan so i can show interest, principal, etc. over time compared by loans.  I found some code that does this, but only for 1 loan where I input the values for that specific loan.  How do I get this to run through each row of my dataframe and treat as a new loan to iterate through and return results in one dataframe with the yield as the columns?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
from dateutil.relativedelta import *


def amortize(principal, interest_rate, years, annual_payments):

pmt = round(nf.pmt(interest_rate/annual_payments, years*annual_payments, principal), 2)
# initialize the variables to keep track of the periods and running balances
p = 1
beg_balance = principal
end_balance = principal

while end_balance > 0:

    # Recalculate the interest based on the current balance
    interest = round(((interest_rate/annual_payments) * beg_balance), 2)

    # Determine payment based on whether or not this period will pay off the loan
    pmt = min(pmt, beg_balance + interest)
    principal = pmt - interest

    # Ensure additional payment gets adjusted if the loan is being paid off
    end_balance = beg_balance - (principal)

    yield OrderedDict([('Period', p),
                       ('Begin Balance', beg_balance),
                       ('Payment', pmt),
                       ('Principal', principal),
                       ('Interest', interest),
                       ('End Balance', end_balance)])

    # Increment the counter, balance and date
    p += 1
    beg_balance = end_balance
```

TRIED THIS :

```
schedule = pd.DataFrame(amortize(base['principal'][0], base['interest_rate'][0], base['years'][0], base['annual_payments'][0]))
schedule
```

But got RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply interest = round(((interest_rate/annual_payments) * beg_balance), 2)

and the code block never seems to finish.

If I do this, it works just fine...but again only for the one loan I manually enter the arguments for - "base" is the name of the dataframe:

```
schedule = pd.DataFrame(amortize(7000, .36, 2.5, 12)) 
schedule
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply and axis 1 to go through the dataframe, slicing with [0] will not work, you would need .values[0] or .iloc[0] for that:

```
base['schedule'] = base.apply(
    lambda row: amortize(
row['principal'], row['interest_rate'], row['years'], row['annual_payments']
    ), axis=1
)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returns one column "schedule", and it has the generator details I assume due to the "yield" vs. "return" in the function.  I tried using one of the dict labels from yield, "Period", and it did the same thing gave me a single row value of "<generator object amortize at 0x000001BEAFD77040>

Comment: the yield is wrong in my oppinion, you should use return after the while statement ended

Comment: Even changing to return I still get a dict in the column, if I add more columns they are just additional replications of the dict

Comment: Please provide sample data: `df.iloc[:5].to_dict()`